# What do the various portions of a compiler returned error mean?

Tags: error-handling, compiler-errors, syntax-error, runtime-error

The question is pretty basic.

Code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
using namespace std;


struct Customer
{
    char name[20];
    char cell[12];
    double bal;
};

int get_total_records_from_file(char * filename)
{
    // Implement this funtion
    return 0;
}


void get_input_from_user(Customer * ptr){
    cin.ignore();
    for(int i = 0; i < customer_count; i++){
        cout<<"Enter Customer Name (1-20 character long)"<<endl;
        cin.getline(ptr[i].name,20);
        cout<<"Enter Cell No. (11 character long)"<<endl;
        cin.getline(ptr[i].cell,20);
        cout<<"Enter Initial Balance"<<endl;
        cin >> ptr[i].bal;
        cin.ignore();
    }
}
```

If I have this error:

```
main.cpp:22:21: error: ‘customer_count’ was not declared in this scope
```

what do the various portions of it mean? That is, what's 22? what's 21? etcetra.

Comment: could you please share your code?

Comment: @user2222 added code

Comment: you try to use undeclared variable  wich is customer_count in the file mail.cpp line 22 and column 21

Comment: When you don't understand something, it's usually worthwhile to check the things you do understand. My first thought would have been to search for the declaration of customer_count and then figure out that it isn't declared anywhere.

Comment: Thank you! What is meant by column here?

Comment: the position of the error in the line causing the error

Comment: thanks a lotttt!! :)